# How can I populate data once it is within a window of time?

Tags: excel, vba, math, excel-formula

I would like cell `J25` to display certain data when it is the next task in the schedule (please see below data).

The next task on the sheet `ROUTINE` should populate into `J25` in relation to the time in cell `B6`

What formula could I use?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could brute force it with merging the multiple scenarios (where cell J25 would be these formulas joined with & eg. J25 =M1&M2&M3&M4&M5&M6&M7 and cell B6 = now() and formatted to hh:mm

```
CELL M1 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=14,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<18),ROUTINE!E5,"")
CELL M2 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=18,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<20),ROUTINE!E8,"")
CELL M3 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=20,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<20.15),ROUTINE!E11,"")
CELL M4 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=20.15,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<20.3),ROUTINE!E14,"")
CELL M5 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=20.3,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<20.45),ROUTINE!E17,"")
CELL M6 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=20.45,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<23),ROUTINE!E20,"")
CELL M7 =IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))>=23,VALUE(TEXT($B$6,"hh.mm"))<24),ROUTINE!E23,"")
```